# PHPmailer how to remove required "From field" as an vaild email

Tags: php, phpmailer

In PHPmailer is there anyway to remove the required "from email" address as your sending it?

I am asking because I am using it to send text through a gateway and the email characters count as characters and they are subtracted from the 140 we are limited to in a text.  I want to put a shorter email address or maybe even a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP requires a sent from email address. It can be any valid email though.

Check out the RFC for SMTP: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt
I know its long and complex, however it should give you a good idea about what is required for email communication, and what you can omit.

Since you need an email in the send from field, try something small like `n@reply` which is valid via the RFC 822 SMTP header format. (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)

Comment: Oh my gosh this website is amazing. That was so fast. You rock. 

How about this as an "off shot" question.  When I send to a number 5555555555@vtext.com from any mail program it allows 140 characters.

BUT WHEN I SEND FROM PHPmailer it allows less. I think it is counting the from Email or header info. Do you know how I can remove this. If I find out the answer I will post it for all. =)

Comment: You are stuck with the email, try short ones so it consumes less characters.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks Joseph. Not sure how squirlmail does it. I know it can be done. Maybe I just have to avoid using PHPmailer or something.

Comment: You can try using the mail() function in php. Its... a little more old and clumsy but might work for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I didn't want to put this as an answer. The mail function is pretty easy. `$to='5555555555@vtext.com'; $subject=''; $message='yo! what up?'; $result=mail($to,$subject,$message);` and thats it. you can set your headers, otherwise it just puts the server default, which I don't think is all that much. I'd give it a try. Oh, welcome to the community. If ohmusama answered your question click the checkbox so others can learn from it :)

Comment: Yes I think it pretty much answered it. I knew I could use the mail function but it usually goes to junkmail and is not as anti spam safe.